# Fixing strange artifacts in an HQX shader

Tags: c#, shaders, monogame, graphic-effects

I'm having an issue implementing an HQX filter that I found in the LibRetro GitHub repository.

- LUT texture was obtained [here](https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/tree/master/hqx/resources)
- Shader file was obtained [here](https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/tree/master/hqx/single-pass/shader-files) (I converted it to compile in MonoGame with SM 5)

This is what I'm getting:

[image: Actual]

And this is what I'm expecting:

[image: Expected]

This is the relevant code:

```
// loading the effect
var effect = base.Content.Load<Effect>(@"Effects\hqx");
var lutTexture = base.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Effects\hq4x");
var projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, 720, 480, 0, 0, 1);
var halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);

effect.Parameters["modelViewProj"].SetValue(halfPixelOffset * projection);
effect.Parameters["texture_size"].SetValue(new Vector2(240f, 160f));
effect.Parameters["LutTexture"].SetValue(lutTexture);

this.effect = effect;
```

Here is how I've configured the required LUT image:

[image: LUT Configuration]

Here is where I draw a pre-rendered texture using the effect:

```
// renderTarget is a 240x160 texture that has the image draw to it first
// the scaling is done by drawing the renderTarget at the higher resolution
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied,
                  SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, this.Effect);
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(this.renderTarget, new Rectangle(0, 0, 720, 480), 
                     this.renderTarget.Bounds, Color.White);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

This is the contents of the hqx.fx file:

```
#define SCALE 4

#define trY 48.0
#define trU 7.0
#define trV 6.0

static float3 yuv_threshold = float3(trY/255.0, trU/255.0, trV/255.0);

const static float3x3 yuv = float3x3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114, -0.169, -0.331, 0.5, 0.5, -0.419, -0.081);
const static float3 yuv_offset = float3(0, 0.5, 0.5);

bool diff(float3 yuv1, float3 yuv2) {
    bool3 res = abs((yuv1 + yuv_offset) - (yuv2 + yuv_offset)) > yuv_threshold;
    return res.x || res.y || res.z;
}

struct out_vertex {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color    : COLOR;
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 t1       : TEXCOORD1;
    float4 t2       : TEXCOORD2;
    float4 t3       : TEXCOORD3;
};

sampler2D decal : register(s0);
sampler2D LUT : register(s1)
{ 
    Texture = (LutTexture);
    Filter = Linear;  
    AddressU = clamp;
    AddressV = clamp;
};

float2 texture_size;
float4x4 modelViewProj;

out_vertex main_vertex
(
    float4 position : SV_POSITION,
    float4 color    : COLOR,
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0
)
{
    out_vertex OUT;

    OUT.position = mul(position, modelViewProj);
    OUT.color = color;

    float2 ps = 1.0/texture_size;
    float dx = ps.x;
    float dy = ps.y;

    OUT.texCoord = texCoord;
    OUT.t1 = texCoord.xxxy + float4(-dx, 0, dx, -dy); //  w1 | w2 | w3
    OUT.t2 = texCoord.xxxy + float4(-dx, 0, dx,   0); //  w4 | w5 | w6
    OUT.t3 = texCoord.xxxy + float4(-dx, 0, dx,  dy); //  w7 | w8 | w9

    return OUT;
}
float4 main_fragment(in out_vertex VAR) : COLOR
{
    float2 fp = frac(VAR.texCoord*texture_size);
    float2 quad = sign(-0.5 + fp);
    float2 ps = 1.0/texture_size;

    float dx = ps.x;
    float dy = ps.y;
    float3 p1 = tex2D(decal, VAR.texCoord).rgb;
    float3 p2 = tex2D(decal, VAR.texCoord + float2(dx, dy) * quad).rgb;
    float3 p3 = tex2D(decal, VAR.texCoord + float2(dx, 0) * quad).rgb;
    float3 p4 = tex2D(decal, VAR.texCoord + float2(0, dy) * quad).rgb;
    float4x3 pixels = float4x3(p1, p2, p3, p4);

    float3 w1  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t1.xw).rgb);
    float3 w2  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t1.yw).rgb);
    float3 w3  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t1.zw).rgb);

    float3 w4  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t2.xw).rgb);
    float3 w5  = mul(yuv, p1);
    float3 w6  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t2.zw).rgb);

    float3 w7  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t3.xw).rgb);
    float3 w8  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t3.yw).rgb);
    float3 w9  = mul(yuv, tex2D(decal, VAR.t3.zw).rgb);

    bool3x3 pattern = bool3x3(diff(w5, w1), diff(w5, w2), diff(w5, w3),
                              diff(w5, w4), false       , diff(w5, w6),
                              diff(w5, w7), diff(w5, w8), diff(w5, w9));
    bool4 cross = bool4(diff(w4, w2), diff(w2, w6), diff(w8, w4), diff(w6, w8));

    float2 index;
    index.x = dot(pattern[0], float3(1, 2, 4)) +
              dot(pattern[1], float3(8, 0, 16)) +
              dot(pattern[2], float3(32, 64, 128));
    index.y = dot(cross, float4(1, 2, 4, 8)) * (SCALE * SCALE) +
              dot(floor(fp * SCALE), float2(1, SCALE));

    float2 step = 1.0 / float2(256.0, 16.0 * (SCALE * SCALE));
    float2 offset = step / 2.0;
    float4 weights = tex2D(LUT, index * step + offset);
    float sum = dot(weights, float4(1,1,1,1));
    float3 res = mul(transpose(pixels), weights / sum);

    return float4(res, 1.0);
}

technique T0
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_5_0 main_vertex();
        PixelShader = compile ps_5_0 main_fragment();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If there are any other details you'd like me to provide please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring the LUT texture you must set the properties in the pipeline as follows:

```
GenerateMipmaps  = false
PremultiplyAlpha = false

// set this to false as it is redundant anyway (the scale 4 texture is 256x256)
ResizeToPowerOfTwo = false
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer (the grey checkmark) after the requisite waiting period (2 days, I think).